# What does "towards" in "They will pay € 2,000,000 towards salary costs" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I have checked various dictionaries (Longman, Merriam-Webster, Cambridge), but I'm still uncertain as to the exact meaning of *towards* in the following sentence:

> They will pay € 2,000,000 towards salary costs

Does it mean that € 2,000,000 will pay **part** of the salary costs, or does it mean that it will **cover** the salary costs? Considering the perhaps most common use of *towards* meaning 'in the direction of' rather than 'reaching', it seems reasonable to assume that it has the former meaning in this example, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To pay towards something means to make a contribution to its costs, as you correctly surmise.

In itself, the phrase gives no indication of the total size of the costs or the percentage that the contribution represents.

Comment: It strongly implies the total cost will be above 2 million Euros.

Comment: @Jonita It doesn't merely **imply** that the costs will be above €2,000,000, it signifies this. Otherwise one would be **paying the costs of** and not **paying towards** the costs of.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You could use this expression even if you had no idea of the total salary costs.  You simply say what the limit of your contribution will be.

Comment: Pay-towards meaning:
To subsidize ; to contribute to paying part of the cost of (something); to contribute to (something).     https://www.yourdictionary.com/pay-towards.                                       
 To subsidize; to contribute to paying part of the cost of (something); to contribute to (something).   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pay_towards

Comment: @RonaldSole you're right, I would be very surprised to find a phrase like this used if the total was under contribution limit, and would probably consider than an error in the reporting. That's part of the point I was making that I think the part of your answer that says "gives no indication of..." is wrong, as the phrase does indicate a lower bound for the total.

Comment: @Jontia Let us graciously compromise there!

Comment: @RonaldSole: Would you accept a sentence like "Insurance will pay [up to $200 towards the cost](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22up+to+*+towards+the+cost%22) of the procedure" in a situation where insurance will pay the full cost if it's ≤ $200? If so, then apparently "towards the cost" doesn't literally signify that the cost won't be fully covered, it's just that you wouldn't say "towards the cost" when you know you can drop the "towards". (This is due to the [maxim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle) of quantity, I think.)

Comment: @ruakh The question isn't really whether I would accept it. It's about the meaning of the expression as defined by agreed dictionaries. Insurance companies typically set limits for different procedures.  Whether they express those limits as **up to** or **towards**  or **a maximum of** would depend on them.

Comment: @RonaldSole: Dictionaries do their best to capture how a term is used, but they can't do a 100% perfect job, because language is messier than fits on a sense line. I agree that it doesn't matter what you personally accept; but it also doesn't matter what a literal-minded interpretation of a dictionary definition would cover. (Though in this case I think the dictionary definitions you quote actually work fine for the case where a payment "towards" something ends up covering all of it.)

Comment: @ruakh Language is wonderfully elastic. We use it as we choose and it's really just a matter of how far we stretch it before it fails its purpose.